# over coming extra . in filenames with move_uploaded_file

Tags: php

the $_FILES['tmp_name'] is empty when I'm trying to move the files on the server to the upload dir- i have put the error down to some pdfs have the filename convention of bla.pub.pdf- could this be my problem? how do i over come it?

Comment: Nope, that is pretty certainly not the problem. What does the `error` field contain in $_FILES?

Comment: error = 1; i have uploaded normal image files fine

Comment: Please include your code. And have you looked at file size as a possible cause?

Comment: See [error messages explained](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: ahhhh-exceeds max file uploads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll need to see your code but it won't be because of the extra dot in the file name.

Take a look at [is_uploaded_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) to verify the file has been uploaded before you move it, if this function returns false it's probably a different issue like file size that is preventing it from being uploaded.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this, but the answer is about as good as it gets when questions are posted without code or due diligence on the part of the asker

Comment: Unfortunately there are idiots as well as geniuses that read SO who can downvote answers.

Comment: Perhaps your question is hard to follow, at least for non-native English speakers.